# Freeing elements of a void pointer array

Tags: c, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation, void-pointers

I am debugging some code written by someone else which has several memory leaks detected by Valgrind. Part of the code which I believe is causing the problems involves `void` pointers:

```
int noElements = 100;
void** ptr = malloc( noElements * sizeof(void*));
for(int i = 0; i < noElements; i++)
{
    ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(void*));
}

//Operation filling the array and doing calculation

free(ptr); //This will not clear the underlying array causing the memory leak?
```

I created a small test program to check the error is where I thought it was (not freeing each `ptr[i]` before calling `free(ptr);`), but I am getting errors when trying to free elements. My test program looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    int num = 10000000; //Large array so I can clearly see memory usage
    void** ptr = (void**) malloc(sizeof(void*) * num);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(void*));
        ptr[i] = &i;    //If I never point elements at anything, this code works
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {       
        free(ptr[i]);       //Crashes here if the elements have been pointed at a variable
    }
    free(ptr);  

    return 0;
}
```

Why would calling free on each array element cause the program to crash if the pointers have actually been assigned?

Comment: because it is not the value returned by `malloc`.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: You are trying to free `&i`.

Comment: If you replace `ptr[i] = &i;` with `*(ptr[i]) = &i;`, then your test program will work (assuming the `malloc` calls do not return `NULL`). However, the pointer stored in `*(ptr[i])` will be pointing to an invalid location `&i` after the `for` loop.

Comment: @IanAbbott type of `ptr[i]` is `void*`. type of `*(ptr[i])` is `void`. this can't use.

Comment: @BLUXPIXY Yes, you are correct. It should be `*(void **)(ptr[i]) = &i;`.

Comment: How does `ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(void*));` make any sense?

Comment: `ptr[i] = &i;` doesn't make any sense either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pointers have been assigned a value which is not what you want.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(void*));
    ptr[i] = &i;    //If I never point elements at anything, this code works
}
```

First you assign a valid memory address that is returned by `malloc()`.
This address could be free'd using `free()`.
But then you assign another address. The address of your local variable `i`. This memory location was not allocated using `malloc()` and hence cannot be free'd. By assigning this address you've lost the dynamically allocated address causing a memory leak.

Your comment is wrong. You already assigned a value that `ptr[i]` points to some valid address. You don't need to assign again. And you should not.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I was assigning a new address to `ptr[i]` to do something with the pointer, when actually to use the pointer I just cast it and use it as an int pointer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In your code

```
  ptr[i] = &i;
```

creates three issues.

1. It makes the actual returned pointer by `malloc()` to be lost (*you're overwriting it*), so you have no shot at `free()`-ing it later, leading to [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).
2. `i` is a local scoped variable (the scope of `for` loop body), and you're storing the address of the variable to be used outside the scope (*i.e., after the lifetime is over*). Outside the scope attempt to access the address of it will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
3. (*Ignoring point 2*) Attempt to `free()` the `ptr[i]` will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) again, as the pointer is not returned by memory allocator function.